# Is it possible to create shortcut to several files in Microsoft Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, shortcut, solution

I'm wondering, is it possible to create something like **shortcut**, **command**, **link** etc to open several solution files at a time via **solution explorer** in **Visual Studio 2013**. The thing is I have several similar projects in one solution. Each of them has `ProjectDatabaseInitializer` class. I want to create **shortcut** which will open all of them at the same time. I have an idea to create bat file which will open this files via Visual Studio and add it to solution but I'm not sure which instance of Visual Studio will windows use to open those files (I'm often using more then one open Visual Studio instances at a time) and I'm wondering is there some native for Visual Studio way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

With the [Favorite Documents](http://vlasovstudio.com/favorite-documents/) extension you can get a menu item to open several files at once.